# Is it proper to use "absent" when a candidate doesn't come to interview?

Tags: word-usage

I know we should use "absent" for someone who doesn't come to a meeting, but when comes to a job interview, is it proper to use "absent"?

You can check the context by the picture below:

[image: Image of an interview assessment form]

PS: I replaced the mark "absent" with "No-show".

Comment: I'd argue it's OK to use "absent" meaning "not present" (at the interview site). I usually hear "the candidate didn't show up/didn't turn up, didn't come" used to describe this.

Comment: I would like to see more context.  Can you give us a sentence where you want to use the word?

Comment: I would no more say that a candidate was absent from an interview, than I would say that a bride was absent from a wedding night or honeymoon.

Comment: @stangdon I use that in an interview score chart. If the candidate doesn't show up, I will mark the candidate with "absent".

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about.  Please give more details.  For example please give the context and an example sentence using "absent".

Comment: @Sayakiss How would you mark them if they had phoned in to say they were ill and would like to arrange an appointment a week ahead? That would seem to me to be a more appropriate use of "absent". If they simply didn't show up I'd write "no show". There has to be a distinction between someone absent with a justifiable excuse and an apology and someone who simply fails to turn up.

Comment: @WS2 - you can't be 'absent' from an event which cannot take place without you.

Comment: @WS2 I will mark "absent"

Comment: @JamesK Please check my picture

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey Yes. I agree with you. I was only suggesting it was slightly less bizarre to mark them "absent" had they simply postponed the meeting. But you have hit the nail on the head - you cannot be "absent" if the event cannot take place without you. If Donald Trump didn't turn up to one of his rallies - you wouldn't simply say he was "absent".

Comment: @Sayakiss So someone who phones in to say they've had a sudden emergency which they need to deal with is categorised with a person who simply doesn't show?

Comment: @WS2 For now, yes, I will mark them all as "no-show". Do you have any suggestions for the sudden emergency guys?

Comment: @Sayakiss Interview rescheduled?

Comment: "no-show" is exactly the phrase that this native speaking Canadian would use to describe someone who didn't show up for a job interview. It's better than "absent" because "absent" is used for regular attendance, not for a one-time event.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a candidate and at least one interviewer for an interview to happen. Someone can be absent from something that actually takes place, such as a meeting, class, etc,  but if a candidate does not turn up to a scheduled interview, then the interview does not happen. There is nothing to be absent from.

> Absent
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> Not present in a place, at an occasion, or as part of something.
>
> *most pupils were absent from school at least once*

[Absent (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/absent)

Comment: An informal term for someone like that is *no-show*.

Comment: [**DNA**](https://www.medicinenet.com/dna_did_not_attend/definition.htm#:~:text=DNA%20(did%20not%20attend)%3A,%22no%2Dshow.%22)) (did not attend): *In the UK, **DNA** is an abbreviation for "**did not attend**." (In the US, the term used for a patient who missed an appointment is "**no-show**.")*

Comment: I suspect that the upvotes are from users who glance at the word "absent" in this answer and think it must be the right one. The author is saying it is not. Candidates who do not turn up at a test or exam are said to be absent, but in interviews I've usually heard the expression [**no-show**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/no-show)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - well, the upvotes are clearly deserved (in my opinion!). I suspect that they are all from wise people who understand the concept of absence.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Why do you suspect that? Do you think most people would use "absent" (and thus wouldn't upvote the real meaning here)? Do you think the answer is/was potentially unclear or misleading? Do you think people generally don't read answers (and, if so, how does your clarification help their non-reading of the answer and might a suggested edit be better)? Hold on, when you say "the right one", do you mean the right *answer* or the right *word to use in this situation*?

Comment: @Mari-LouA If it was an exam and one person was not there then I see nothing wrong with describing that person as "absent". But as MWH says you cannot be absent from something which cannot take place without you - the event simply doesn't happen, so there is nothing to be absent from.

Comment: @NotThatGuy see the OP's recent edit, it now includes the term "no show" that was suggested in several comments but not seen in Michael's answer. Their answer explains well when "absent" should not be used but it didn't suggest any alternatives